# Displaying all the prime numbers from 1 to variable

Tags: java

Im trying to diplay all the prime numbers (including 1) from 1 to variable n but nothing is being displayed. If you ca point what is wrong that would be great.

```
public static void primeCalculator(int n) {
    System.out.println("All the prime numbers from " + n + " to 1 are:");

    int result;
    int divisor = 1;
    int nPrime = n;

    while (divisor <= nPrime);

    {
        if (nPrime % divisor == 0) {
            result = 1;
        } else if (nPrime % divisor != 0) {
            result = 0;
        }
        if (result == 0) {
            System.out.println("/n" + divisor);
        }
        divisor++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code. Paste it into any online auto-formatting tool for Java, before posting here. This is illegible.

Comment: Remove the semicolon after your while condition. `while (divisor <= nPrime); {` should be `while (divisor <= nPrime) {`.

Comment: Formatting your code makes the error very obvious.